# Python QT5 - QTWidget Layout grow/shrink to maximumSize/minmumSize

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a layout question for python with qt5.
So, there is a main window with a normal vertical layout with 2 widgets.
The first one is a widget with a scrollarea which has a minimumSize & maximumSize set.
The second one is another widget with yet another scrollarea widget.

My goal is this. I load some content in the first widget and depending on the content it should either shrink or grow to the set min/max sizes and if it gets bigger than maxsize the scrollarea should take effect.
The second widget should always take all the rest of the available space.

I've tried all kinds of sizePolicy combinations but can't get it to quite to work. The second widget has a sizePolicy of Prefered/Prefered with vertical stretch set to 1, so it takes all the available space for itself.

The 1st widget has a miniumSize of 100 and a maximumSize of 250. So ideally it should shrink to something between 100-250 if the content is less and it should grow to 250 and activate the scrollbar if the content is getting bigger.

If I update the content of widget one (i.e. by clicking on a button) it should 1. resize/shrink/grow so the content fits, but not smaller than 100 and not larger than 250. If I have less content I should not be able to make widget one reszie to 250 - it shoudl always just take the exact needed height.

Any idea on how to do that?

[example layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbgiP.jpg)

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: <pre><code></code></pre>

Answer (score 0):

Your scrollarea isn't going to change size, because it's a scrollarea.  It doesn't need to size itself to its content, because the size of the contents of a scrollarea is basically unbounded.  You can just scroll more.  If you want to change the size of the first scrollarea, you're going to have to set its height manually.